# Change permission to mount disk with rdesktop on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions, remote-desktop, mount

I installed rdesktop 1.7 on Ubuntu 10.4 and ran the following commands:

```
sudo umount /media/Tal
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0000 /dev/sdb1 /media/Tal
rdesktop -0 -r sound:local -f -u administrator -r clipboard:PRIMARYCLIPBOARD -r
disk:tal=/media/Tal myip
```

Tal is an external NTFS hard drive that connects via USB to a Windows 7 machine. I see it from the computer, and I can access its files and create new files/folders, but when I try to copy a new file to a folder I get the error message

> You need permission to perform this action
>
> You require permission from computer's administrator to make changes to this folder tal on *my computer's name*
> Disk from Remote Desktop Connection

I've tried using `chmode` and `chowne` but I've read that they don't work with NTFS. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo -i
```

Then enter your password. Or try

```
sudo nautilus
```

Then enter your password.

Answer (score 0):

chmod ...file permission  just works on the ext x file system.
no effect on NTFS,linux is just compatible with ntfs(general read and write,no other secure strategy)

Comment: you are right, i know it already. i need solution that i can have permission from the Remote Desktop session to this Hard Disk, when i redirect it to Remote Windows Computer.  do you have a clue how to do it?